# Search and extract between workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, extract

I'm trying to use the following code to search one cell in each row. If the search value matches a portion of the cell in that row, the entire row is copied and added to the end of another range in another workbook.

```
Sub GetRowsWithMatchingDates ()


Dim toThisWorkSheet As Worksheet,  fromSourceWorkbook As Workbook
Dim NextFreeRow As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim currentRowDate As String
Dim currentRow As Long
Dim TodaysDateAsString As String
Dim currentRowDate As String

TodaysDateAsString = 20150320


Set toThisWorkSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ImportedData")
NextFreeRow = toThisWorksheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

Set fromSourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "JUIDTesting.xlsb")

     With fromSourceWorkBook.Sheets("DataToBeSearched")


           For i = 1 to To LastRow
           LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
           currentRowDate = Mid(toThisWorkbook.Range("B" & i + 1).Value, 3, 8)
           currentRow = .Range("A" & i + 1).Row

                If TodaysDateAsString = currentRowDate  Then

                     currentRow.Copy
                     toThisWorkbook.Range("A" & LastRow + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

               Endif

           Next i

     End With

fromSourceWorkBook.Close False

End Sub
```

`

I'm just beginning to use for and with and copy paste code so this could be totally jacked up.

Answer (score 0):

lastrow needs to be before your loop, right now it is undefined and defaults to 0. So you are doing a for i = 1 to 0 esentially.

it should be

```
LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 to To LastRow
    currentRowDate = Mid(toThisWorkbook.Range("B" & i + 1).Value, 3, 8)
    currentRow = .Range("A" & i + 1).Row

    If TodaysDateAsString = currentRowDate  Then

        currentRow.Copy
        toThisWorkbook.Range("A" & LastRow + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    Endif

Next i
```

That would correct your first problem.

Your second problem is that toThisWorkbook is not defined anywhere + it is in a with from source workbook, and you do not have a worksheet defined.

Would need to be something like

```
ThisWorkbook.toThisWorkSheet.Range("A" & LastRow + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

but also keep in mind that will just keep overwriting the same row because that is what you told it to do. lastrow + 1 = will always be the same constant.

Comment: troy, did you follow what I was saying?

Comment: does it make any sense to you?

Comment: So late here but Yes I did. Thanks, that helped a lot.